# Handling CRUD with mongodb using Express.js building a REST API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I am currently working on a REST API using Express 4. The API will only be a layer to access a mongodb database. The database will have hundreds of different objects. For example there will be some looking like

Alt1

```
{
 name: Sting,
 number: Int
}
```

Alt2

```
{
    name: Sting,
    temp: Int,
    length: Int
}
```

My questions is now does each object needs its own data model with mongoose and basic CRUD routes defined?

For the example above there would be two datamodels and  2*4 routes to define the basic CRUD operations?

Comment: This is way too broad and open to opinions. Try [searching](https://www.google.com/?q=mongoose%20crud) Or even at a basic level, see the documentation for ["plugins"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html). There are either existing solutions or ways to do this DRY.